# How do I find which external drive a folder is mounted from?

Tags: mount

For instance, let's say I mounted `dev/sda1` and `dev/sda2` in the distant past. I'm in `media` and I see folders `drive1` and `drive2`. What command can I use to see which one is `sda1` and which one is `sda2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`lsblk`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsblk) should do the trick. Or [`mount`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount). Or [`findmnt`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/findmnt).

Comment: lsblk is exactly the simply answer I'm looking for and isn't provided as an answer to the question my question is marked as a duplicate of. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
df /media/drive1 /media/drive2
```

The ostensible purpose of the `df` command is to display how much free space there is on a filesystem. But since it also gives the name of the device (in the first column) and you can pass it any file on a filesystem, it's also a way to answer the question “on what device is this file stored?”.

If you want more information about the device and you're running a non-antique Linux, try `lsblk /dev/…`